Can we implement $\omega^{CK}_1$ using $\omega^{CK}_2$ as an oracle?
Let $\omega^{CK}_1$, $\omega^{CK}_2$ denote the first two admissible ordinals greater than $\omega$. Suppose we have an unknown well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ of the order type $\omega^{CK}_2$ as an oracle. How to implement a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ (or any computable subset for simplicity) of the order type $\omega^{CK}_1$?
Most of this question is from the other question asking about how to do this using $\omega^{CK}_1 + 1$. But the method couldn't be easily extended.

This is currently open! In fact, it is unknown whether $\omega_1^{CK}\cdot\omega\ge_s\omega_1^{CK}$; here "$\ge_s$" is the standard notation for "Medvedev-computes," which is the notion you're asking about.
Answering a question in the comments in the question you link to, Hamkins and Li showed that $\omega_1^{CK}+\omega\ge_s\omega_1^{CK}$. In fact, their argument (or at least the version of it I learned from my advisor) generalizes easily to show that $\alpha\ge_s\omega_1^{CK}$ for every $\alpha\in[\omega_1^{CK},\omega_1^{CK}\cdot\omega)$. But that's as far as we know right now.
(That said, a quick warning: the proof of Theorem 42 in the paper linked above is wrong.)
In general very little is known about the $\ge_s$ relation on ordinals. Besides the above, here are some questions I don't know the answers to:

What is the smallest pair of ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ which are $\le_s$-incomparable? (It is known that such ordinals exist, in fact there is a club $C\subset\omega_1$ such that any two distinct elements of $C$ are $\le_s$-incomparable, but the upper bound on the smallest such pair that we currently have is terrible.)

Do every pair of countable ordinals have an $\ge_s$ upper bound (let alone least upper bound)? If we use uniform hyperarithmetic reducibility in place of Turing reducibility the answer is yes, via the natural sum, but this doesn't seem to work for $\ge_s$ itself.


(The results  mentioned in the previous bulletpoints are from a sadly-languishing paper of mine; I'll add a link when it's available.)

EDIT: Here's the proof that $\alpha\ge_s\omega_1^{CK}$ for any ordinal $\alpha\in[\omega_1^{CK},\omega_1^{CK}\cdot\omega)$:
Fix such an $\alpha$, and let $n$ be the smallest natural number such that $\omega_1^{CK}\cdot n>\alpha$. Note that this means that whenever we write $\alpha$ as a sum of $(n+1)$-many ordinals, at least one of those ordinals must be $<\omega_1^{CK}$.
Now given a copy $A$ of $\alpha$, let $S$ be the set of increasing $n$-tuples of elements of $A$, and for each $\sigma\in S$ let $T_\sigma$ be the tree of simultaneous descending sequences through the $(n+1)$-many segments of $A$ corresponding to the elements of $\sigma$. The Kleene-Brouwer ordering $KB(T_\sigma)$ associated to $T_\sigma$ will be roughly the size of the smallest of the $(n+1)$-many segments produced by $\sigma$; in particular, it will be computable, and we have $$\omega_1^{CK}=\sum_{\sigma\in S}KB(T_\sigma).$$

Could we do this to $\omega_1^{CK} \cdot \omega$, by using $\omega + 1$ segments? That is, to insert an element (and make the exact values branches in the guess) below the final element in the "tuple" for each step down into the tree. Also, $n$ doesn't seem to need to be the smallest in the case you have given.

The idea of implementing $\omega_1^{CK}$ using $\omega_1^{CK} + \omega$ in the linked paper in Noah Schweber's answer:
Given an oracle that encodes some ordinal, and a specific point $x$ that represents the ordinal $\alpha$, there is an algorithm that outputs $\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, or a finite ordinal otherwise: Do buffered copy of all points below $\alpha$, but only flush each time a new maximum below $\alpha$ is reached.
Guess each point to be representing $\omega_1^{CK}$, which is the largest limit ordinal under $\omega_1^{CK} + \omega$. Enumerate all the points from each output of the above process, that are all the ordinals smaller than $\omega_1^{CK}$. Copy them and the whole set of ordinals smaller than them, and order the points related to different guessed and enumerated points only according to the guessed and enumerated points, in a way of order type $\omega$ (not one guess following another guess, but say anti-diagonals of the guesses and the enumeration).
The outputs from wrong guesses and duplicated copies don't matter, because $\omega_1^{CK}$ is additively closed, that is, the sum of any finite number of ordinals smaller than $\omega_1^{CK}$ is also smaller than $\omega_1^{CK}$.
To extend to $\omega_1^{CK} + \omega \cdot n$, one could guess a list of limit ordinals and tries to only output the lowest one, and flush each time every ordinal in the list had a new maximum below it.
Maybe Noah Schweber had a version that is easier to generalize. But my idea about the next steps is to do incremental guesses that the list would have a new element under each limit point, which probably works up to any ordinal smaller than $\omega_1^{CK} \cdot 2$.

I've added the argument I had in mind (which I learned from my advisor) to my answer.
